# Why would Plotly not recognise attribute 'offline'?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm following the tutorial plotly timeseries, [here](https://plot.ly/python/time-series/). I've also amended the code to allow for offline charts in Jupyter, [here](https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/#start-plotting-online).

I'm trying to plot a timeseries in Jupyter Notebook. I get the following error.

> AttributeError: module 'plotly.plotly' has no attribute 'offline'

As far as I can see I've carried out all the instructions but can't get it to work with the method they suggest.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

py.offline.init_notebook_mode()

data = [go.Scatter(x=dataload.date, y=dataload.spend)]

py.offline.iplot(data)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-c9b2e8d8907c> in <module>()
      2 import plotly.graph_objs as go
      3 
----> 4 py.offline.init_notebook_mode()
      5 
      6 data = [go.Scatter(x=dataload.date, y=dataload.spend)]

AttributeError: module 'plotly.plotly' has no attribute 'offline'
```

Does anyone have a suggestion to why I might be getting this error, could it be a local setup issue?

Comment: Because tt doesnt have the attribute. You should call `from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot`, and then use `init_notebook_mode()` alone. Also `py.offline.iplot(data)` should be only `py.iplot(data)`.

Comment: i.e. the modules you want to call is actually `plotly.offline`, and not `plotly.plotly`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use:

```
 import plotly
 plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
```

don't use: `import plotly.plotly as py`

You are referring different documentation. Use https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/#initialization-for-offline-plotting
Here it also provides more information regarding how to use help function.

For tutorial in offline mode: https://github.com/SayaliSonawane/Plotly_Offline_Python

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you. Do you think there is a reason why the official documentation uses plotly.plotly?

Comment: No I don't know. You can refer this plotly offline tutorial : https://github.com/SayaliSonawane/Plotly_Offline_Python/tree/master/Scatterplot/Basic_Scatterplot